# Google Cloud C# API Never Callback

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the below code to access my storage:

```
private static IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer GetInstalledApplicationCredentials()
{
string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxx";

X509Certificate2 certificate;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data", "path.p12"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        certificate = new X509Certificate2(ms.ToArray(), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    }
}

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] {
            StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl
    },
}.FromCertificate(certificate));

return credential;
}

        private static StorageService GetStoreageService()
    {
        var service = new StorageService(
            new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = GetInstalledApplicationCredentials(),
                ApplicationName = "app"
            }
        );

        return service;
    }

public static byte[] DownloadAudio(string fileName)
    {
        var service = GetStoreageService();

        var req = service.Objects.Get(bucketName, fileName);
        var readobj = req.Execute();

        var downloader = new MediaDownloader(service);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            downloader.Download(readobj.MediaLink, ms);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

In the line var readobj = req.Execute(); my application just blocks and never give me a response. I already tried with JSON and with OAuth. the only difference is that with OAuth in the IIS Express it works but outside IIS Express it is not. Using P12 or JSON I have the problema both in IIS or IIS Express.

Any idea?

Thank you,
Murilo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but try

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is not the problem, the problem is that some calls was with .Result and causing the deadlock. I changed all the call to use await and it worked. Thank you very much